# First Class Functions In Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, functional-programming

I am working my way through this article on functional programming (https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/one/an-introduction-to-functional-programming) and trying to do the exercises in Ruby.

One exercise defines two functions, zero and one. Zero takes a string parameter and returns string index 1 - end if the first character is 0, One does the same thing but only if the first character is one.

Here are the ruby implementations:

```
def zero(s)
  if s[0] == "0"
    return s[1..(s.length)]
  end
end

def one(s)
  if s[0] == "1"
    return s[1..(s.length)]
  end
end
```

The problem asks you to write a method called rule_sequence that, given a string and an array of functions, returns the result such that the functions are invoked one at a time -- the first function is invoked in the whole string, the second function invoked on the return value of that string, etc. If, at any point, the one of the functions returns nil, return nil.

The Python implementation is:

```
def rule_sequence(s, rules):
    if s == None or not rules:
        return s
    else:
        return rule_sequence(rules[0](s), rules[1:])
```

However, since it doesn't seem like Ruby has support for higher order functions, the most elegant solution I could come up with was the following:

```
def rule_sequence(string, rules)
  if rules.length == 0 or string.nil?
    return string
  else
    return rule_sequence(rules[0].call(string), rules[1..rules.length])
  end
end

puts rule_sequence('0101', [lambda { |s| zero(s) }, lambda { |s| one(s) }, lambda { |s| zero(s) } ])
```

Can anyone come up with something more terse than passing or calling lambdas?

Comment: Those aren't functions, they are methods. That's your whole problem! If you redo the exercise with functions (called `Proc`s in Ruby), it'll Just Work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll take this exercise as an opportunity to show how Ruby supports higher order functions.

Let's go one step back and rewrite the `zero` - `one` functions.
You can notice they have quite a lot in common.
Let's try to exploit that by writing a lambda that can generate both

```
tail_on_prefix = lambda {|prefix|
  lambda {|str| str[1..-1] if str[0] == prefix}
}
```

We can now easily define `zero` and `one`

```
zero = tail_on_prefix.("0")
one = tail_on_prefix.("1")
```

To `rule_sequence` now!

```
rule_sequence = lambda {|str, rules|
  if (str.nil? or rules.empty?)
    str
  else
    rule_sequence.(rules[0].(str), rules[1..-1])
  end
}
```

now calling `rule_sequence` looks a bit better, doesn't it

```
rule_sequence.("100101", [one, zero, zero]) # => "101"
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer the lambda literal syntax rather than passing a block to `Kernel#lambda` for creating lambdas, but that's just a style preference. It makes them look close to lambda literals in other languages such as ECMAScript, Haskell, C#, Java, Scala, CoffeeScript, etc. One tiny advantage might be that being built-in syntax, a compiler might perform some optimizations that it cannot do with a method like `lambda`, which, after all, may be overridden or monkeypatched to do something completely different … however, I have no idea, if any existing (or even future) compiler does that.

Comment: Instead of nested `lambda` calls, you could define your function as `tail_on_prefix = -> (p, s) { s[1..-1] if s[0] == p }` and use [`curry`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Proc.html#method-i-curry) to obtain `zero` and `one`, i.e.  `one = strip_prefix.curry['1']`

Comment: if you want pass this `tail_on_prefix` somewhere, you still have to pack it as `x = mathod(:tail_on_prefix)` and then explicitly call `x.call <args>`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
puts rule_sequence('0101', [method(:zero), method(:one), method(:zero)])
```

Just BTW, `s[1..(s.length)]` can be written as `s[1..-1]`, and `rules[0].call(string)` can be written as `rules[0].(string)`.